# Problems with git push: I can see the commit but the status is modified

Tags: git

The scheme is the following:

1. A desktop PC used as a server (pc1) OS: Windows 7
2. A laptop used by me (laptop1) OS: Windows 10
3. A laptop used by a coworker (laptop2) OS: Windows 10

The 3 computers share the same network, therefore I created a shared directory. I want the physical files on all the machines, also the pc1. Therefore I can not use bare repository.

**First step - Initialization:** I copy the files in pc1. Then I give the 3 commands:

```
git init
git add --all
git commit -m "Initialization"
```

with these commands I initialize an empty repository, I add all the files, and then I do the commit.

Finally I give the command `git config denyCurrentBranch updateInstead` to push modified files from laptop1 or laptop2.

**Second step - Work on a local machine:** In a local machine, say laptop2, `git clone <pathToServer>` to have the repository on the local machine.

I or my coworker performs the modifications on the files, then we give:

```
git add .
git commit -m "modifications"
```

In this way a new commit with the modifications is created. Finally I give the command `git push origin master` to insert the new modifications on pc1. The operation is concluded with success.

**Step 3 - issue on pc1:** When I enter in pc1 inside the repository, I see a star symbol that indicates the modified files have not been committed, but they are in modified status. I verify this by the command `git status`. But when I give the `git log` command I can see the commit hash and message. How can I solve this problem? Is my configuration wrong?

A problematic and naive solution that I tried is to give inside pc1 the commands:

```
git add --all
git commit --amend
```

it is problematic because it rewrites the history on pc1. Also, to keep it simple I am working with just a branch, the master one, in all the machines.

Comment: This all sounds like a bad idea. // When you issue `git add .`, are you in the working tree’s root or in a subfolder?

Comment: I am in the working tree's root.